Changed behaviour of Interpolation
Consider the following code:
Interpolation[Table[{i, 2 i}, {i, 10}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][{5}]

Mathematica 13.2 on Windows 11 returns {10}, while version 14.1 returns 10.
What may be the reason for this change in behaviour?

@Domen You're right, I misread the code. Deleting.

@Domen You're right, I misread the code. Deleting.
